# change color of scroll bar

Tags: scrollbar

i want to change style of scroll bar ,for this i used below css ,but i want do use it for specific div on page not for whole page.
how can i customize it using div class or id

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #A8A8A8; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can achieve this using element id,

Try this,

```
#div1::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 12px;
}

#div1::-webkit-scrollbar-track  {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

 #div1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  {
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #A8A8A8; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 }

#div1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}​
```

Hope it will work...

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/Uvng8/2/)

Note: i think, it's working fine in chrome. but ff & ie it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

If you really want some custom scrollbars then there are some hacks you can use in Javascript and CSS - Nice article on [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

There are plenty of jQuery plugins out there too. One I have used is called [Lazybars](http://lazybars.suiji.co.uk/) - really simple to implement.

Hope this helps

Comment: Looks like Lazybars plugin does not hide native scrollbars (as I see on demo page in Firefox). And it's not free. There are lots of free jquery plugins that can do more

Answer (score 0):

CSS customization currently is supported by webkit browsers only (Safari, Google Chrome and Opera now). IE and Firefox do not support CSS styles for scrollbars. To make crossbrowser CSS customizable scrollbar you have to use javascript solution that emulates scroll behavior or replaces native scrollbars with custom elements (native scrollbars are under these custom scrollbar or hidden by wrapper with `overflow:hidden`).

There are lots of free jQuery plugins. Scrollbar emulators *(such as [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), [Malihu Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/), [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.com/perfect-scrollbar/), etc...)* provide full control over scrolling content, but have more js (to emulate and handle all events) and scrolling behaior differs from native scrolling behavior. Also, lots of scrollbars on the same page may slow it down.

Scrollbars that uses native scrolling (such as [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/), [Scroller](http://formstone.it/scroller/), [Baron](https://github.com/Diokuz/baron/), etc...) are less in code and guarantee that scrolling will always work (even if plugin does not work because of any bug) + less code (as there is no need to emulate scrolling) + automatically supports all scrolling features like scrolling to focused element, scrolling on text selection, scroll to anchor element, touch scrolling, etc...

You can compare custom scrollbars plugins [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=drive_web)